# OpcNetApi executa uma leitura mais rápida enquanto MarikonOPC Explorer está aberto

Tags: c#

Minha aplicação executa a leitura de 24 tags de um servidor localhost RsLinx Classic.

Contudo, passei a notar que a leitura das tags são mais rápidas quando o software MatrikonOPC Explorer está sendo executado e lendo as mesmas tags de minha aplicação.

Quando o MatrikonOPC Explorer é fechado a leitura das 24 tags dura em torno de 180ms a 220ms. Mas quado o mesmo está aberto e executando a leitura das mesmas tags simultaneamente o tempo de leitura da minha aplicação é em torno de 30ms!

Segue o evento backgroudworker utilizado para leitura contínua das tags OPC:

```
    void workerGroupRead_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker _worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        ItemValueResult[] values;

        if (listOPCItems != null && listOPCItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (items != null && items.Length > 0)
            {
                while (!_worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    stopwatchReader.Restart();

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)

                    try
                    {
                        if (IsConnected && !_worker.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            values = server.Read(items);                                

                            ReadValuesResult(values);
                        }

                        TempoLeitura = stopwatchReader.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    }
                    catch 
                    { 
                        stopwatchReader.Reset();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Já verifiquei as configurações DCOM e permissões e não encontrei nada que me parecesse óbvio.

Caso alguém tenha alguma sugestão, 
desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complicado dar uma resposta conclusiva para este tipo de questão, pois é uma situação difícil de reproduzir (ainda mais por envolver hardwares externos especializados).

Ainda assim, quero deixar algumas sugestões (especulações):

Aparentemente, parece que a leitura lenta ocorre em virtude de um ciclo inicialização-execução-fechamento do servidor OPC. Quando o "Explorer" já está ativo, parece que esta inicialização é dispensada. Vale lembrar que o OPC é só uma interface padronizada (assim como o ODBC é para banco de dados no Windows), cuja implementação nem sempre é a mais otimizada. Verifique se não existe alguma documentação que descreva como efetuar leituras em lotes (batches) - provavelmente há um procedimento para manter o "ambiente aberto".

Além disso, executaria um [profiler de performance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) comparando os dois ambientes para tentar entender qual é o ponto de gargalo deste *overhead*. Analisando o código fonte da biblioteca (via um *[decompiler](http://ilspy.net/)*), podemos conseguir "dicas" sobre o que código está executando que eventualmente podemos antecipar antes de uma execução em lote com essa.

Verifique também com o seu fornecedor do hardware se não há uma interface específica para o .NET, ao invés de utilizar OPC. Algumas fornecedoras oferecem e até estimulam o uso de bibliotecas nativas .NET (Ex: [Beckhoff](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcadscomlib/html/tcadscomlib_intro.htm)). Pela minha experiência (não muito vasta neste ramo, confesso), a diferença de performance é brutal.

Comment: Realmente o erro ocorria no processo de inicialização. Não estava sendo inicializado um grupo de leitura das tags Opc na minha aplicação. O grupo de leitura era criado pelo MatrikonOPC quando o mesmo era aberto e configurado para ler o mesmo conjunto de tags que a minha aplicação. Obrigado pela ajuda!